# GCC not complaining about uninitialized variable

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Why is it that gcc is not complaining about j being uninitialized? If I remove the j += 10 it will actually complain...  Compile with -Wall (tested with gcc 4.9 and 5.3).

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int threshold = 100;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        if (j >= threshold)
            break;
        j += 10; /* comment this line to enable uninitialized variable warning */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It complains it's uninitialized, or unused? And what is your warning level by the way?

Comment: (Used with -Wall)
warning: ‘j’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

Comment: add `-O1` to get the warning for this code (in gcc 5.3).  It doesn't try very hard to make these warnings, changing the optimization level may make it stumble on the problem

Comment: the warning goes away at O2 and O3 because the whole loop is optimized out; to stop this, insert a call `void g();  g();` in the loop

Comment: ok, I was using 5.3.0 with switches `-std=c11 -Wall -O1`. All versions of gcc on the online tester (4.7 through to 5.3.0, and 6.1) give the warning with these switches for your code as posted

Comment: Indeed.  Scary...  Didn't realize the optimization level matters.

Comment: Strange, it should warn in both cases, at least that's what clang does. You can explore different compilers [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An optimiser can figure out that the whole loop is pointless, but it is a bit complicated. The loop is pointless because the values of i and j are not used after the loop, and j is used inside the loop only to decide when to break early, which doesn't matter either because the number of iterations of the loop doesn't matter. So in this situation, if you initialised j to a random number, you would get exactly the same result. So the compiler *may* not issue a warning because nothing harmful will happen.

Obviously you have undefined behaviour, so the whole app could just crash because of the uninitialised variable. But that is up to the compiler, so if that happened, you should get a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely compiling this at high optimization levels, which cause the loop to be removed for optimization purposes.

So try compiling at `-O1` or `-O0` even.

If that doesn't make it show up, ensure that you use high warning levels, with `-Wall` and `-pendantic`

Comment: You are correct, I didn't releaize the optimization levels removed the loop. 
However, why is the loop not removed when I remove the j+= 10...  Strange.

Comment: @ErikOomen goes to show that nothing except `-O3` matters when talking about optimization